# Two WFEs without NLB?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, load-balancing, network

Can I have 2 WFEs without using NLB in which case it will work as fail over but not as load balancer?

Or if I am using more than 1 WFE then I have to use NLB and without it, it will be like single WFE?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. You can use 2 WFEs without load balancing (via NLB or other hardware).
It won't automatically fail-over, but if one WFE has an issue, you can access your content via the other WFE.

If you are using a dns name (e.g, http://portal.company.com) instead of machine names you have two options:

1) enter both IPs for DNS entry which will provie "dumb" load-balancing (it will route traffic to servers not considering an actual "load" on each server). Drawbacks of DNS load-balancing are listed here: [DNS Load Balancing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-robin_DNS)

2) you can point your DNS records to one WFE and then "manually" fail-over to the other one by updating the DNS records to the other WFE.

Comment: Thanks. So basically 2 WFEs without NLB is manual fail over. And if I use NLB then it becomes automatic fail over?